# R's mice imputation alternative in Python

Tags: python, r, data-imputation

What is Python's alternative to missing data imputation with `mice` in R? Imputation using median/mean seems pretty lame, I'm looking for other methods of imputation, something like `randomForest`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [fancyimpute](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fancyimpute)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library [HERE](https://github.com/jeweinberg/Pandas-MICE). You are able to impute the values of your dataset using linear models with an Sklearn type interface.

Comment: Instead of requesting contributions to your repository, you could edit the answer and include more details about the current features of the library.

Answer (score 1):

Is this [statsmodels MICE implementation](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/imputation.html) an option?  I also heard that an implementation of MICE is being merged into the development branch of scikit-learn but I can't find any info on that.